# I can’t seem to change the width of my columns inside my ion-item [ionic2]

Tags: html, css, ionic2

```html
<ion-item-group *ngIf="tuesdayJson">
            <ion-item-divider class="" sticky> {{tuesdayJson.dayOfWeek}}
            </ion-item-divider>
              <ion-item class="transparency" *ngFor="let event of tuesdayJson.agendaEvents">
                <ion-row class="agenda-event-row {{event.rowType}}">

                  <ion-col width-25>
                    item 1
                  </ion-col>
                  <ion-col width-25>
                      item 2
                  </ion-col>
                  <ion-col width-25>
                      item 3
                  </ion-col>
                  <ion-col width-25>
                      item 4
                  </ion-col>

                </ion-row>
              </ion-item>
</ion-item-group>
```

This is my code. I expect that when I add a width value to my ion-col tag, I'd get a certain width. In this case I want four equal columns.

This is what I get: [image]

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? The column width thing works for me perfectly fine inside ion-content but not inside ion-item.

Comment: what's your ionic version? what's the `ionic-native` version in your `package.json`?

Comment: "@ionic-native/core": "3.1.0", "ionic-angular": "2.3.0",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the last update to Ionic 3 they've changed the way we use the grid. There's no more `width-x` attribute for `<ion-col>`. They changed to 12 cols grid scheme (much like the one in Bootstrap).

So in this case your code needs to be like this:

```
<ion-row class="agenda-event-row {{event.rowType}}">
  <ion-col col-3>
    item 1
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-3>
    item 2
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-3>
    item 3
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-3>
    item 4
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

If you need further explanation about the grid, screen sizes and everything else just see the [Ionic 3 grid Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/).

Hope this helps :D

Comment: You're welcome :D and if you can accept my answer as correct so it can help other ppl.

Comment: Question, do you know how I would go smaller than col-1? One of my icons still has too much space on the sides.

Comment: nvm, I sort of solved it. 

You do col-2 col-10 and then inside col-10 you do col-1 col-10 col-1

pretty neat, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I may be late. But considering being helpful for someone else, following way works for me in Ionic 4.

```html
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size='2'>
        1 of 3 (wider)(wider)(wider)(wider)(wider)(wider)
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size='8'>
        2 of 3 (wider)(wider)(wider)(wider)(wider)(wider)
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size='2'>
        3 of 3 (wider)(wider)(wider)(wider)(wider)(wider)
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

</ion-grid>
```

But total of sizes is 12.